# General term for the sum $\sum \sin(k)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, trigonometry, proof-writing, trigonometric-series

How do I prove that:

$$\sin(1)+\sin(2)+\cdots+\sin(n)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)\sin\left(\frac n2\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12\right)}?$$

I have tried to to use the formula $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ but without any success.

Comment: If you know how to write trig functions in terms of complex exponentials, this becomes a simple exercise in geometric series (if you don't know how to write trig functions in terms of complex exponentials, then the day you learn how will be one of the best days of your llife).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You can prove it by induction.
Here's a sketch of the inductive step:
\begin{align}
\sin(1)&+\sin(2)+\dots+\sin(n)+\sin(n+1)=\frac{\sin(\frac{n+1}2)\sin\frac n 2}{\sin(\frac12)}+\sin(n+1)\\
&=\frac{\sin(\frac{n+1}2)\sin\frac n 2+\sin(n+1)\sin(\frac12)}{\sin(\frac12)}\\
&=\frac{\sin(\frac{n+1}2)\sin\frac n 2+2\sin(\frac{n+1}2)\cos(\frac{n+1}2)\sin(\frac12)}{\sin(\frac12)}
\end{align}
Now in the second term of the numerator, you can linearise  the factor $\;2\sin(\frac12)\cos(\frac{n+1}2)$ with the formula
$$2\sin a\cos b=\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b).$$

Comment: I don´t quite get why did you added sin(n+1) to [sin((n+1)/2)sin(n/2)]/sin(1/2).Care to explain? the rest I understand.

Comment: It's for the inductive step: one has to deduce the formula for $n+1$ terms from the formula for $n$ terms.

Comment: For n+1 shouldn't it be [sin(n/2 +1)sin(n/2+1/2)]/sin(1/2)?

Comment: The final result? It should be $\;\dfrac{\sin(\frac{n+2})2\sin(\frac{n+1})2}{\sin(\frac12)}$ (replacing $n$ with $n+1$ and $n+1$ with $(n+1)+1=n+2$.

Comment: yes. That is the form for n+1 but I still don't get why you added sin(n+1)

Comment: Because the case $n+1$ is the formula for $sin(1)+\sin (2)+\dots+\sin(n+1)$. The sum for the case $n+1$ is just the sum for the case $n$, plus a supplementary term. Isn't it clear?

Comment: Ohh!You added sin(n+1) to both sides.I only saw it in one side. Okay I get it.I think I can take it from here.